# Bar plot: Loop through a list of element and make an automatic annotation on labels that are on the list

Tags: python, matplotlib

> I would like to loop through a list of element (annotation_list) and automatically make an annotation on top of the corresponding label saying "Not updated". As in the image.
> I would also like to make an annotation in red - centered horizontally and 3/4 vertically saying "Confidential, for internal use only"
> Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPta1.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import calendar

Country_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Country_name=["Algeria","Belgium","Brazil", "China","France","Germany","India","Italy",
              "Poland","Mongolia","US","Switzerland"]
print(len(Country_name))
units_sold =[100, 1050, 1000, 950,300, 500, 250, 700, 600, 550, 500, 450]
n=len(units_sold)
line=[round(units_sold[0]/x,1) for x in range(1,n+1)]

anotation_liste=["Algeria","Germany","Mongolia"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)
plt.xticks(Country_num,Country_name, rotation=90)
plot = ax.bar(Country_num, units_sold)

for rect in plot:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.002*height,'%d' % 
    int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

    #### MISSING CODE MAKE ANNOTATION WITH ARROW
    


plt.plot(Country_num, line, linewidth=2.0)
plt.margins(x=0, tight=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow has been added in the annotation. Data coordinates are set in data and text coordinates are set in offset. Also, the character annotations are set to the upper right position (x=0.9, y=0.8) in 'ax.text()'. For more information, see [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-annotation-demo-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import calendar

Country_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
Country_name=["Algeria","Belgium","Brazil", "China","France","Germany","India","Italy",
              "Poland","Mongolia","US","Switzerland"]
print(len(Country_name))
units_sold =[100, 1050, 1000, 950,300, 500, 250, 700, 600, 550, 500, 450]
n=len(units_sold)
line=[round(units_sold[0]/x,1) for x in range(1,n+1)]

anotation_liste=["Algeria","Germany","Mongolia"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(12, 6)

boxdic={'facecolor':'w',
        'edgecolor':'b',
        'boxstyle':'square',
        'linewidth':1}

plt.xticks(Country_num,Country_name, rotation=90)
plot = ax.bar(Country_num, units_sold)

for rect in plot:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.002*height,'%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
    if height == 500:
        #ax.text(rect.get_x() , height+100, 'Not\nupdated', bbox=boxdic, color='r')
        ax.annotate('Not\nupdated',
                    xy=(rect.get_x()+.4, height+30), xycoords='data',
                    xytext=(0,60), textcoords='offset points', color='r',
                    ha='center',va='center',
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',
                                fc="k", ec="k",
                                ),
                    bbox=boxdic)

ax.text(0.9, 0.8, 'Confidential,\nfor internal use only',ha='center',va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.plot(Country_num, line, linewidth=2.0)
plt.margins(x=0, tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]